# Restore Droid Explorer Backup

Tags: droid-explorer

How do I use Droid Explorer to restore a back up either the enhanced or normal ab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restore you open Windows Explorer and navigate to the backup directory.

```
c:\users\[username]\Android Backups\[device_id]\
```

There you will see the backups for the device. You can then double click on the backup file and restore it to the device.

[image]

If it is an Enhanced Backup, it will only be allowed to restore to the device that it was taken from.

You can also convert Android Backups to Enhanced backups, and vice-versa by right clicking the backup and choose 'convert to xxxx'.

You can also choose to unpack a backup. This will basically extract the contents of the backup so you can browse it on your computer.

When you start the restore, it will run the `adb restore` command on your device, using the backup selected.

Comment: double clicking on the file opens Droid Explorer though it crashes as soon as I push the restore button. To remove the startup error about permissions of root adb I have adb insecure installed on my device and activated at boot.

Comment: The device is a Nexus 7 2nd generation ROOTED.

Comment: @DonMoody, the crash is a bug, I have reproduced it, created the issue on the issue tracker, and will get it fixed in the next release.

Comment: @DonMoody Disclosure: Ryan is the dev of the fabulous *Droid Explorer* :)

Comment: @Izzy, thanks, Yeah, I should have said that... DonMoody I hope the rest of this answer is actually useful to you. So if there wasn't a bug that prevented it from running successfully, this would tell you how to use it :)

Comment: @RyanConrad No prob. Though we have that policy-of-disclosure here, it's safe to assume more than half of the people on ASE are aware ot the fact in this case – I just wasn't sure about our new member :D

Comment: @RyanConrad I look forward to the new release. Thank you for the responsive reply.

Comment: When I right-click a .ab file and choose unpack, then type the password, nothing seems to happen. Where should the unpacked file appear?

Comment: @RobFisher it would be in the same location. Make sure you have java installed, as it is required to unpack.